# How to get all children given a parent id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called "Person" that has "mother" and "father" fields (one-to-one relationship pointing to the same class), so now I want to get all the children of a person
How can I do this?

**This is the Model**

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :mails, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :phones, dependent: :destroy

  has_one :spouse, class_name: 'Person'
  has_one :father, class_name: 'Person'
  has_one :mother, class_name: 'Person'
end
```

And **this is the Migration**

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :rut, unique: true
      t.string :dv
      t.string :names
      t.string :paternal_surname
      t.string :maternal_surname
      t.date :birth_date
      t.date :death_date
      t.string :civil_status
      t.string :sex
      t.string :nationality

      t.references :father
      t.references :mother
      t.references :spouse

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I want to access to the children with:

```
Person.children
```

But I'm really new at RoR and I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that a Person has many children. Similar to how you have stated that Person has many mails and phones.

From there, adjust your code to say that a Person belongs to a father instead of has one.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :mails, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :phones, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Person'

  has_one :spouse, class_name: 'Person'
  belongs_to :father, class_name: 'Person'
  belongs_to :mother, class_name: 'Person'
end
```

Comment: The problem with `belongs_to` is that I can't insert a record without a father or mother. That's why I used `has_one`
UPDATE: I used `optional: true` in belongs_to, but when I call Person.children it gives me this error: `NameError (uninitialized constant Person::Child)`

Comment: I think this is my mistake, try adding the class name of Person to the has_many children line.